# Is belated partitioning possible?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10, postgresql-11

I've got a PostgreSQL 10+ (probably 11) database to work with. As the tables are growing fast, but implementation time is scarce, my approach is to first setup the whole scheme, so that the app can run on it. After that, I'd like to introduce partitioning (by date) on some tables.

**Is belated partitioning possible?**

Practically I mean that I create partitions by date and that already-inserted data is then automatically re-assigned to those partitions (if applicable). Also, if it's possible, is this a good approach or are there better alternatives?

I guess that reorganizing a big table needs its time, but that's ok.

Comment: No, that's no possible. But why don't you just create partitioning now. It's not that much more effort than creating the table without it (and if you plan for partitioning you should definitely start with Postgres 11 right away)

Comment: Because I'd like to do the partitioning with a pgSQL script that does it automatically (creating new partitions for upcomming months), which needs some testing. Good to know belated partitioning isn't possible. There also is no re-organization command to force it?

Comment: You might want to have a look at [pg_partman](https://github.com/pgpartman/pg_partman)

Comment: Oh that might actually help me a lot with managing partitions! Going to look into it. I just had time to cross-read it, I guess with it I still must have a partitioned table first and can't do it afterwards?